# Wrong keys in macbook keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, input-source

The keys that were supposed to give tilde and back-tick in the keyboard are giving § ±, respectively. My input source is U.S, as you can see in the image, and my keyboard layout is the following:
[image: keyboard layout]
[image]

I tried to format my mac but it didn't work as well.
What's is the problem that is occurring? Is there a way it can be solved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your machine thinks the keyboard is of the ISO type instead of the ANSI type.  ISO keyboards have tilde/backtick on an extra key next to the Z.  See if [this note](http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html) can help:

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately there is no keyboardtype.plist  in my Library/Preferences. I ran /System/Library/CoreServices/KeyboardSetupAssistant.app/Contents/MacOS/KeyboardSetupAssistant and nothing's happened. Finnaly I tried to reset the SMC, but again it didn't work.

Comment: @EduardoHashimoto In addition to karabiner, you could make a custom layout with http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele